# Enabling port 80 with iptables works but does not work with ufw

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, ufw

After creating a new compute instance in oracle cloud with ubuntu as the os, I installed nginx.

Now to open port 80 I tried the commands `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'` and enabled ufw. But still I couldn't access the server on port 80 from the browser. However, if I use the command `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`, I can access the server on port 80. To make sure this is the case, I recreated new compute instances and tried this out multiple times.
From what I understand ufw serves as a simpler interface to the much more complicated iptables.

Is there an explanation as to why this works like this?
`

Comment: I would suggest you instead just do `sudo ufw allow http` instead of requiring 'nginx http' - 'http' is the more generic port 80 and usually works properly.  Also, **DO NOT** mix `ufw` and straight `iptables` commands - use one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I kept googling, I found this: [Opening port 80 on Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Compute node - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794217/).

From [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54810101):

> I figured it out. The connectivity issue was due to Oracle's default
> use of iptables on all Oracle-provided images. Literally the very
> first thing I did when spinning up this instance was check ufw,
> presuming there were a few firewall restrictions in place. The ufw
> status was inactive, so I concluded the firewall was locally wide
> open. Because to my understanding both ufw and iptables look at the
> netfilter kernel firewall, and because ufw is the de facto (standard?)
> firewall solution on Ubuntu, I've no idea why they concluded it made
> sense to use iptables in this fashion. Maybe just to standardize
> across all images?
>
> I learned about the rules by running:
>
> ```
> $ sudo iptables -L
> ```
>
> Then I saved the rules to a file so I could add the relevant ones back
> later:
>
> ```
> $ sudo iptables-save > ~/iptables-rules
> ```
>
> Then I ran these rules to effectively disable iptables by allowing all
> traffic through:
>
> ```
> $ iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
> $ iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
> $ iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
> $ iptables -F
> ```
>
> To clear all iptables rules at once, run this command:
>
> ```
> $ iptables --flush
> ```
>
> Anyway, hope this helps somebody else out because documentation on the
> topic is rather sparse.

Comment: This will not explain why UFW doesn't work.